# E-bike brake lever sensor wires loose

Tags: electric-bike

In my E-bike, sensor wires has come out from the left side brake lever. Please see attached photo from link below. How do I re-connect wires to sensor. How do I get access to sensor terminals? Do I have to buy a new brake lever with sensor cable attached?

[image]

Comment: For some models it's possible to replace the sensor and wiring without replacing the brake lever.  I've done this with Tektro but finding spares was hard.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the photo, there's a small knurled plastic ring around the cable.  Try unthreading that and the switch should come out.

Then you'll need to strip the wires and solder to the switch, and provide mechanical support using heatshrink etc.

When you refit the switch, make sure the wires are not being pulled.  I'd suggest adding more zip-ties to hold the wires to the brake cable for support.

Do take progress photos and add them as an answer of your own.  If you feel this is beyond you, anyone handy and competent with electrics/wiring should be okay to do this.

---

The purpose of this sensor is to cut off the motor if you start braking.  If you're comfortable with letting off the throttle, or coasting to brake, then the motor should shut off any assistance.

The sensor switch is probably a "normally closed" and will open when you press the brake lever.  So to get the bike working temporarily you could bare and twist the two wires together.

Your last resort is to buy a new left-hand brake lever with a sensor.   Also, check the right-hand lever and make sure the wire is not under strain now.

Comment: Thank you Criggie for prompt reply. I removed the black colour small knurled plastic ring but switch won't come out.

Comment: my best option is to twist the two wires together and ride. When I brake, stop pedalling which will stop the motor. Later I will buy a left brake lever and join the existing wires to new brake lever wires as I do not have access to other end to remove the existing wires completely and connect the new wires.

Comment: @WimalPerera the downside of the is if you shift gears while timing a gap in traffic, the pedalling to change gears will cause the motor to kick in.  When I borrowed an ebike with a broken cable to one brake, I had to get into the habit of  always using both brakes

Comment: The fault I saw was that the manufacturer had cable-tied the wire to the brake cable to relieve strain, really close to the switch.  That worked until the barrel adjuster on the brake lever was used for its intended purpose a couple of times.  And the switch could be NO or NC.  It's a logic input to the motor controller rather than necessarily part of a fail-safe circuit. I still reckon the switch should come out somehow.

Comment: @chris Noted your comments. I am in contact with e-bike local supplier to direct me to their recommended service shop to have a look. Bike shops near me won't look at it as make of my bike was not sold by them.

Comment: @WimalPerera I've found that with the e-bike I used to look after.  The LBS would deal with normal bike stuff (including rebuilding the motorised wheel) but electrical bits were up to me.  That's no problem as I do simple electronics and wiring quite a lot, but sourcing parts was hard.

Comment: I have enough electronics junk and other scrap materials that rather than twisting the wires together I'd make a temporary on/off switch mounted on the bars (using a fitting from an old front light or phone bracket).  That's not an option for everyone of course

Comment: @chris, Good Idea. I will try to mount a switch.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem and fixed it.

As per this picture, I reconnected two wires with solder.

[image: connect two wire]